# How to assign log4j output message to a variable

Tags: java, string, logging, log4j

I want to assign log4j message that goes to console to my variable,
for instance:

```
log.info("some info");
String info = // info message from log
```

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is not what log4j was designed for. What is it you want to do?

Comment: when log4j prints message, it prints in custom pattern with some extra information, I need that message to use somewhere else, I just do not want to write extra code to build the same message that log4j already built.

Comment: Write an appender that collects logstrings and let your code access its buffer

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand for what, I think you message is more complex that simple string.
You can try to implement own custom java Appender and to register it in Logger.
Appender will work as listener of messages and you will be able to implement some custom logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
Message message = new SimpleMessage("some info");

PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
Log4jLogEvent event = Log4jLogEvent.newBuilder()
                                   .setLevel(Level.INFO)
                                   .setMessage(message)
                                   .build();

String formattedMessage = layout.toSerializable(event);
```

The process of forming an exact string that the logger is up to print is quite tedious. You need to programmatically describe the settings you normally write in a configuration file. Then, you should build an event that will give the context to your settings.

For the sake of simplicity, I took the default layout, and built an event with a simple `INFO` message. But I am pretty sure there should be a way to load the configuration from an external source. Try: `PatternLayout.createPatternParser(Configuration)`.